# How to get parameters from URL in python flask

Tags: python, web-services, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, url-parameters

I have following codes:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ q.title }}</td>                    
  <td>{{ q.text }}</td>
  <td><a href="http://localhost:8000/answer?t={{ q.title }}"> Answer </a></td>
</tr>
```

and in the flask I have this code:

```
@app.route("/answer" , methods=['GET'])
   def answer():
      atitle = request.args.get('t')
      return render_template('answer.html' , value=atitle)
```

I tried differend ways and also used:

```
@app route("/answer/<t>" , methods=['GET'])
```

but none of them is working and I keep recieving "GET /answer/Java HTTP/1.1" 404

Comment: are you sure your url encoding is correct? Can you print the url on console before making the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you've got something else running on port 8000 and flask is listening on a different port (likely 5000). Try using `url_for` instead of constructing the url yourself...

```
<a href="{{ url_for('.answer', t=q.title) }}">Answer</a>
```

See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=url_for#flask.url_for